# AngularJS controller scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller:

```
appControllers.controller('MeetingListController', ['$scope', '$route', '$location', function($scope, $route, $location){
    console.log($scope.go);

    $scope.progressRun = function($event){
        $scope.go = true;
    };
});
```

I don't undersand because when go variable changes value in `progressRun` function, 
`console.log` doesn't  show right value and it called before and after `progressRun` function.

Comment: You must call console.log($scope.go); within a function

Comment: you must use console.log inside your function where the $scope value changes

Answer (score 3):

Simply move your `console.log()` after you change the `go` variable in the `progressRun()` function...:

```
 appControllers.controller('MeetingListController', ['$scope', '$route', '$location', function($scope, $route, $location) {
    $scope.go = 'initial value you want to assign to this variable';

    $scope.progressRun = function($event) {
        $scope.go = true;
        console.log($scope.go);
    };

 }]);
```

**UPDATE:**
If you want to log the variable value *anytime* it changes (even when it's value should be changed *outside* `progressRun()` function, use:

```
$scope.$watch('go', function() {
    console.log($scope.go);
});
```

Just after `go` variable initialization (as correctly @Shreevardhan suggestes).

Comment: but I need to use value into controller, and $scope.go != true, undefined.

Comment: Just set an initial value to your variable (possibly `false` ?) just entering the controller... See my updated answer...

Comment: This must be comment not answer

Answer (score 0):

Either log the value after changing

```
$scope.go = true;
console.log($scope.go);
```

Or, use `$watch` on the variable

```
$scope.$watch('go', function() {
    console.log($scope.go);
});
```

PS: `$watch` will log each time the value changes.